# optional union transformation in Informatica developer

Tags: informatica

I want to conditionally union 2 csv files using the UNION transformation.

Depending on the input parameter, the mapping would do any of the following:

Union A and B
Only A goes through the union transformation. B is ignored
Only B goes through the union transformation. A is ignored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand requirement correctly,

- For condition 1, only TableA goes to target
- For condition 2, only TableB goes to target

You can do this using FILTERS and UNION. Pls refer to below diagram.
After reading form source you can attach two filters to filter data as per requirement. And then union them together before writing into target.
Filter A will have condition like - `IIF(Condition1=True, True,false)`
Filter B will have condition like - `IIF(Condition2=True, True,false)`
Pls note, i used IIF so you can write your own complex expression if you want. Whole mapping should look like this -

```
Source Qualifier A --> FilterA -->
                                   | UNION --> Target
Source Qualifier B --> FilterB -->
```

Comment: I'll just add that a single Filter after the Union can also provide the requested functionality. Just mark the source and use a bit different condition, like `IIF(INSTR($$src_to_read, SRC)>0)`, where `SRC` would be a port with values `A`, `B` (for each source respecively) and `$$src_to_read` parameter value could be `A`, `B` or `AB`.

Comment: Agree to this, boss. I applied filter earlier so that we process less number of records :)